# MongoDB unable to push to array when grabbing schema by _id

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nosql

I have been trying to add a subscription feature to my website where the person subscribes and that class is added to their class array in the users model... Here is my code:

```
app.post("/subscribe", function (req, res) {
    const newClass = req.body.subClass;
    const id = req.user.id
    const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
    User.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: new ObjectId(id) },
        { $push: { classes: newClass } },
        { upsert: false, new: true }
    );
    res.redirect("/dashboard")
});
```

Here is my schema:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    password: String,
    secret: String,
    classes: [String]
});
```

and the model I am pushing to: 
`const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema)`

All help is appreciated

Comment: use normal id. ``` User.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: id },
        { $push: { classes: newClass } },
        { upsert: false, new: true }
    ); ``` or use "findByIdAndUpdate"

Answer (score 0):

```
app.post("/subscribe", async function (req, res) {
    try {
    const newClass = req.body.subClass;
    const id = req.user.id
    const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
    await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
            id,       
            { $push: { classes: newClass } },
            {upsert: true, new: true }


   );
   }
   catch(err) {
    console.error(err);
   }
    res.redirect("/dashboard")

});
```

Here's mongoose references [link](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate)

Comment: For some reason this will also not work... do you think it could possibly be something with the array being empty? I am not very familiar yet with mongoose

Comment: check newClass value. put debugger or console. Updated code with async await and try/catch.

Comment: use upsert: true.